# Batch script to check a service is running on a list of servers

Tags: batch-file

I'm fairly new to coding but basically I have the script below which will check if a local service is running and start it if it isn't. The thing is I want the script to check if the service is running on a list of servers that would be stored in servers.txt, and then output the result to results.txt. If anyone could help me i'd very much appreciate it.

Thanks

Derek

net start | find "servicename" > nul 2>&1 
if not .%errorlevel%.==.0. goto startservice 
goto skip

:startservice 
net start "servicename" 
echo service restarts @ %date% %time% >> C:\results.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use the PowerShell `get-service` cmdlet similar to:

```
get-service -name $ServiceName -computername server1, server2, server3, serverX | format-table -property MachineName, Status, Name, Displayname -auto
```

If you're not too familiar with PowerShell, run this command at the prompt which will give you really good info:

```
get-help get-service -full
```

PowerShell also builds in really great "about's" run this command to get info on how to do foreach in PowerShell:

```
get-help about_foreach
```

To get a list of all available about topics run this:

```
get-help about
```